# option clash geometry with tikz when using for a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdftex, tikz-styles

```
\usepackage[hmargin=1.15in,vmargin=1.115in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta,automata,er,calc,backgrounds,mindmap,folding,patterns,decorations.markings,fit,snakes,shapes,matrix,positioning,shapes.geometric,through,arrows,decorations}

\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}
```

Comment: The above i have put in a seprate tp.tex file and i input into my beamer to use tikz then i get option clash inside this tp file

Comment: Don't add additional questions in edits. If you have a new question, ask a new question

Comment: And if you ask a new question, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of mere code fragments

Answer (score 4):

Beamer already loads the `geometry` package, so you cannot load it again with different options. But this is no problem, because beamer provides its own command to change the left and right margin size.

Setting the vertical margin on the other hand does not make much sense with beamer. At the top, beamer will automatically calculate the required height of the headline (depending on the theme you use) and because beamer does not automatically start new pages, the concept of a bottom margin is also more or less theoretical, the content will just overflow. Normally beamer assumes a `vmargin` of 0, changing that may badly affect the placement of all kinds of elements.

You also don't need to load `xcolor` and `graphicx`, both is loaded automatically. And `snakes` is superseded by the `decorations` library, so you should not need this either.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[hmargin=1.15in,vmargin=1.115in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{
%graphicx,
caption,subcaption}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta,automata,er,calc,backgrounds,mindmap,folding,patterns,decorations.markings,fit,
%snakes,
shapes,matrix,positioning,shapes.geometric,through,arrows,decorations}

\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.15in,text margin right=1.15in}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Kind help with edit I apologize

Comment: @sriram If you want to use such extraordinary large margins like `1.15in`, you would need to scale down the picture considerable. For example using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]` (I would not use such very large margins)

Answer (score 1):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hmargin=1.15in,vmargin=1.115in}{geometry}
\documentclass{beamer}
...
```

and then do not load `geometry`, it is done by `beamer`