# Kind help to make the below tikz picture to size of beamer slide with adding at top size as it may effect other slides without picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
   \usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
   \useoutertheme{Smoothbars}
   \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
   \setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries} 
   \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}
\subject{...}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Plan wyk?du}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{
%graphicx,
caption,subcaption}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta,automata,er,calc,backgrounds,mindmap,folding,patterns,decorations.markings,fit,
%snakes,
shapes,matrix,positioning,shapes.geometric,through,arrows,decorations}

\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{24,40,120}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle];
    \node (v0) at (0:3) {$V_0$};
        \node (v1) at (72:3) {$V_1$};
        \node (v2) at (2*72:3) {$V_2$};
        \node (v3) at (3*72:3) {$V_3$};
        \node (v4) at (4*72:3) {$V_4$};
        \node (v5) at (5*72:3) {$V_5$};
        \node (v6) at (6*72:3) {$V_6$};
        \node (v7) at (0:6) {$V_7$};
        \node (v8) at (72:6) {$V_8$};
        \node (v9) at (2*72:6) {$V_9$};
        \node (v10) at (3*72:6) {$V_{10}$};
        \node (v11) at (4*72:6) {$V_{11}$};
        \node (v12) at (5*72:6) {$V_{12}$};
        \node (v13) at (6*72:6) {$V_{13}$};

                \draw (v0) -- (v1) 
                (v1) -- (v2)
                (v2) -- (v3)
                (v3) --(v4)
                (v4) --(v5)
                (v5) --(v6)
                (v6) --(v0)
                (v7) -- (v8) 
                (v8) -- (v9)
                (v9) -- (v10)
                (v10) --(v11)
                (v11) --(v12)
                (v12) --(v13)
                (v13) --(v7)
                (v0) --(v7)
                (v1) --(v8)
                (v2) --(v9)
                (v3) --(v10)
                (v4) --(v11)
                (v5) --(v12)
                (v6) --(v13); 

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above picture also does not fit into a page. Need help
If I add `\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.15in,text margin right=1.15in}` then all my slides are in problem

Comment: This is similar to [Option clash `geometry` with `tikz` when using for a `beamer` presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466557/5764).

Answer (score 2):

Margins of 1.15 in are very large for beamer, I would not use such large margins. The total paper width is only 12.8 cm so about half of your page would be empty margins.

If you really must use them, you can scale the image using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[hmargin=1.15in,vmargin=1.115in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{
%graphicx,
caption,subcaption}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta,automata,er,calc,backgrounds,mindmap,folding,patterns,decorations.markings,fit,
%snakes,
shapes,matrix,positioning,shapes.geometric,through,arrows,decorations}

\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.15in,text margin right=1.15in}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={draw,shape=circle}}
    \node (v0) at (0:3) {$V_0$};
        \node (v1) at (72:3) {$V_1$};
        \node (v2) at (2*72:3) {$V_2$};
        \node (v3) at (3*72:3) {$V_3$};
        \node (v4) at (4*72:3) {$V_4$};
        \node (v7) at (0:6) {$V_7$};
        \node (v8) at (72:6) {$V_8$};
        \node (v9) at (2*72:6) {$V_9$};
        \node (v10) at (3*72:6) {$V_{10}$};
        \node (v11) at (4*72:6) {$V_{11}$};

                \draw (v0) -- (v1) 
                (v1) -- (v2)
                (v2) -- (v3)
                (v3) --(v4)
                (v4) --(v0)
                (v0) --(v1)
                (v1) --(v0)
                (v7) -- (v8) 
                (v8) -- (v9)
                (v9) -- (v10)
                (v10) --(v11)
                (v11) --(v7)
                (v7) --(v8)
                (v8) --(v7)
                (v0) --(v7)
                (v1) --(v8)
                (v2) --(v9)
                (v3) --(v10)
                (v4) --(v11)
                (v0) --(v7)
                (v1) --(v8); 

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version for hibernators.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcounter{Angle}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.15in,text margin right=1.15in}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
    \node[regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides=5,minimum
    size=3.27cm,rotate=-90] (small 5gon){};
    \node[regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides=5,minimum
    size=6.54cm,rotate=-90] (large 5gon){};
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={draw,shape=circle,fill=white}]
     \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(\Y+1)}] in {7,...,11}
     {\node (v\Y) at (small 5gon.corner \Z){$V_\Y$};
     \node (v\X) at (large 5gon.corner \Z){$V_{\X}$};
     \draw (v\Y) -- (v\X);}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @sriram You're welcome! (and please use smaller margins :)

Comment: @sriram P.S. I removed a few nodes because they were printed on top of each other

Comment: Drawing the pentagons with `shapes.geometric` may make the code much shorter.

Comment: @marmot If only there would be a hibernating being, who also is an tikz expert and could post an answer that shows the advantages of `shapes.geometric` library ....

Comment: @marmot You deprive me of the pleasure to upvote your answer :( But thanks a lot for your edit!

Comment: @marmot Voting is really a mystery. This morning we had a question that a) seemed to be about bash (so completely off-topic),  b) was in German, c) was very unclear and d) only had a random `biblatex` tag. It was upvoted....